# tokens stuck in smart contract

Tags: tokens, etherdelta

I tried to purchase some tokens on ether delta, but it kept saying tha it would not go through. However, when I came back to my computer, my funds had disappeared. I have located the tokens, but don't know how to retrieve them.

I can see the tokens [here](https://deltabalances.github.io/#0x0e8aedff1a1095c11ea799cb13a027b654645508), but not when I look at the ether delta interface.
Grateful for any help

Answer (score 1):

You need to have ETH balance in your address (0x0e8aedff1a1095c11ea799cb13a027b654645508) to be able to pay for the gas for the withdrawal.

Also you should be able to see your token balance when you visit the trading page for your tokens. In this case: [TEU-ETH](https://etherdelta.com/#TEU-ETH)

Answer (score -1):

pretty simple, u have to put get some ether into your main wallet and then go to Etherdelta, set the gas price to 21 in the top right menu and go to withdraw and type in the amount of tokens and click withdraw.